# writing an SQL statement with JOIN

Tags: sql, join

so I have 3 tables

table 1: team

```
| team_id   | name   | 
-----------------------
|     1     | alpha  |
|     2     | beta   |
|     3     | gamma  |
```

table 2: buildings

```
| building_id  | name     |
---------------------------
|    1         | Baxter   |
|    2         | LexCorp  |
```

table 3: team location

```
| team_id | building_id |
-------------------------
|    1    |      1      |
|    2    |      1      |
|    3    |      2      |
```

What I need now is an sql query that will list the names of the teams located in the baxter building and I cant for the life of me even think where to begin on this one, im quite new to SQL

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=join+statement

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=sql+basics

Comment: Thanks for these links however I already googled this myself and have read loads about joins but cant get this to work, I wouldn't of posted here if I could of worked it out from what I read on google

Comment: @user1680768 did you try the solution that I wrote you below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
SELECT team.name FROM team_location
INNER JOIN buildings ON buildings.building_id  = team_location.building_id  
INNER JOIN team ON team.team_id = team_location.team_id 
WHERE buildings.name = 'Baxter'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this gives me a syntax error saying missing operator

Comment: thats sql server syntax, if you use any other sql, you should mention it :) see it as pseudocode and adopt it

Comment: sorry for the late reply but thanks a lot this worked once I altered it slightly to work with access. I had to put the first join in brackets and this worked great!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.NAME
FROM team as t
INNER JOIN teamLocation AS tl ON t.team_id=tl.team_id
INNER JOIN buildings As b ON tl.building_id=b.building_id
WHERE b.name='Baxter'
```

Please check this sql fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/45e2e/1